# What ES6/React magic is used in this class inheritance?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Going through the TodoMVC example of [Redux](https://github.com/gaearon/redux) I have found this unusual example of class inheritance. The class Header is probably extending React.Component as per usual (as should all React components, right?), but it is not explicitly stated in the code. What am I missing? How does this code work?

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import TodoTextInput from './TodoTextInput';

export default class Header {
  static propTypes = {
    addTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  handleSave(text) {
    if (text.length !== 0) {
      this.props.addTodo(text);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header className='header'>
          <h1>todos</h1>
          <TodoTextInput newTodo={true}
                         onSave={::this.handleSave}
                         placeholder='What needs to be done?' />
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The "magic" is simply a well defined interface. All that react needs is an object (component) with a `render` method. It doesn't care how the component manages its state. It provides helpers (`React.Component`) but you don't have to use them if you don't need them. It also only calls lifecycle methods if they are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the methods defined by [`ReactComponent`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js) (`setState()` and `forceUpdate()`) you don't have to inherit from it.

As such, it isn't an example of class inheritance or magic because neither is happening here :)

Comment: Huh, ok — that makes sense. Thanks!

BTW, in this case, is it right that the first line, importing React and PropTypes, would actually only need to be importing PropTypes and that's it (omitting the React default import...)?

Comment: You always need to import React as JSX is just sugar for `React.createElement(...)`